# Are clear VS is clear

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> However, as long as the learning benefit of the games are clear, adults will enjoy them just as much, with the competitive aspect of a game perhaps adding to their engagement.

In the above sentence, is it correct to say "are clear", to my ear it should be "is clear". Is the subject "(learning) benefit" and as such take is as the form of to be?

Comment: It should be **is** clear instead of **are** clear, since the subject of the verb is **"The learning benefit"** not **"the games"**.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The sentence you quote is wrong. It should be "is". The subject of the verb is "the learning benefit". That is singular, so the writer should have used the singular verb, "is".

It's a common mistake. There's a plural noun right before the verb, "the games". But it's not the subject of the verb, it's part of a prepositional phrase that is acting as an adjective modifying the subject.

When in doubt in complex sentences, it can be helpful to drop out all modifiers. In this case, we could simplify it to "... the learning benefit is/are clear ..." It's then clear :-) that the verb should be singular.

Comment: Interesting that we don't see the reverse error: “The benefits of this approach is obvious.”  Perhaps the erroneous rule is: the verb is plural if *any* component of the subject is plural.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "the learning benefit (of these games) is clear" or "the learning benefits (of these games) are clear" - it matches the subject.

If it is a general concept, use is.  For example, if you explain something in math to someone, you end by asking: "Is that clear (to you)?" Or you can say "Are we clear?", "Understood?", or "Do you get it?"

Any of these (especially if emphasised) can also have a menacing tone if you say it after something like "I've told you repeatedly to put the milk back in the fridge after you're done."